# Как сделать чтобы в столбец автоматически вставлялось уникальное значение?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Нужно чтобы в каждой строке, у которой заполнен столбец **B**, чтобы автоматически проставлялось уникальное значение в эту строку в столбец **A**

Буду благодарен за информацию как это сделать.

Comment: Где брать уникальные? Или какими они должны быть? Прикрепленный пример или ссылка на таблицу с примером ускорит получение решения.

Comment: Да что угодно, пусть это будет даже временная метка в unix

Answer (score 1):

Простейшее решение.

Значения в столбце `В` будут располагаться в ячейках, которые принадлежат каждая определенной строке. А каждая строка имеет свой уникальный номер!

Первая строка - это обычно заголовок таблицы. Пишем формулу в ячейку А2 и протягиваем вниз:

```
=ЕСЛИ(B2="";"";СТРОКА())
=IF(B2="";"";ROW())
```

Если "упорядоченная" (по возрастанию) уникальность не подходит, то без скрипта на `JS` не обойтись.

Answer (score 0):

=ЕСЛИ(A1 <> ""; СЛУЧМЕЖДУ(1; 10))

Comment: А куда это прописывать?

Comment: Можно... Но `СЛУЧМЕЖДУ` - функция летучая и при любом изменении на листе будет пересчитываться, т.е. возвращаемые значения будут изменяться. Плюс к этому (или минус к решению) - функция возвращает только целые числа, что очень сильно сужает диапазон значений и увеличивает вероятность повтора. Если уж применять похожее решение, то лучше с функцией СЛЧИС (случайные числа в диапазоне от 0 до 1)